# How can I find ALL the records with max attribute across records in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several records with several attributes (A, B, C, D).

I want to be able to find which record has the higher value for a given attribute, such as D.

```
Team.of_city(seller_lead.city).with_access_to(seller_lead.state).max_by{ |team| team.rank }
```

For example, The above code gives me only one city but there are multiple cities with the same maximum rank. How do I get them all?

Comment: please include a code sample

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with a subquery in the database:

```
Team.where(rank: Team.maximum(:rank)).
     of_city(seller_lead.city).
     with_access_to(seller_lead.state)
```

Comment: Thought of this. But, here we'll be re-arranging the scopes which will bring wrong results for sure.

Comment: You could create a scope like `max_on, ->(column) { where(column => maximum(column)) }`. Can you explain under which circumstances the order of scopes might affect the result?