# Rails Scopes: Return record(s) that have maximum cost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Book` model which has an attribute of `cost`.

I want to write a query that grabs all `book` record(s) that have the highest `cost`.

I need to account for the scenario where more than one `book` might *share* the exact same highest `cost`.  In that scenario, I grab all of those `book` records that share the highest `cost` (not just one of them).

Example Datebase for the `books` table:

```
id | cost 
 1   4
 2   10
 3   7
 4   20
 5   15
 6   20
 7   3
```

so the scope I would need to write would return *two* `book` records: the record with the `id` of `4`, and the record with the id of `6`.

I think the answer involves using the `maximum` method, the `having` method, and the `group` method, but I'm having trouble putting all the pieces together for the scope.

Here is one thing I have tried but it doesn't work.  Appears to only return the last record with the highest `cost` as opposed to *all* records with the highest cost:

```
Book.group(:cost).having('books.cost = ?', (Book.maximum(:cost)))
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32351211/382982) answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it:

```
  scope :most_expensive_books, -> {where(cost: self.maximum(:cost))}
```

This scope executes two queries:

- a query to determine what the maximum `cost` is.
- Then: it uses that *value* for the maximum `cost` within a `where` clause.

The SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT MAX("books"."cost") FROM "books" 
Book Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."cost" = ?  [["cost", 20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find out the max price, and then use the `select` method to grab all the book records that matches the max price.

```
max_cost = Book.map {|book| book.cost}.max

Book.select {|book| book.cost == max_cost }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Would you happen to know how to turn this into a scope?